# Apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be built with Xcode 5.1.1 or later, and iOS 7 SDK

Tags: ios, xcode5, app-store-connect

Got this error today with the new iTunes connect web page.

[image]

My xCode version is

[image]

and my SDK is

[image]

My previous submission went through with the old web pages. Now the new web page keeps complaining about this error with my new version. Anyone seen the same issue?

Comment: I've got the same thing right now, please post an answer if you figure it out

Comment: I'm seeing the same here.
Here's my theory: they now want us to use Xcode 6.0 GM with the iOS 8.0 SDK (both of which were released earlier today in GM form), and they simply forgot to update their error message.
I can't test this theory, as I am not in control of the release process at my company. Somebody care to give it a try?

People are talking about this on the [Apple Developer forum](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1037477).

Comment: I'm getting this with 6.1.1 GM, which is installed itself *over* 6.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, it might be an issue of their web site. Just tried now with a cleaned build and it went through for review.

Comment: and how do you do that? i'm not sure how to create another build.. i don't see where that option is..

Comment: You can change the value for key "Bundle Version". For example, if you have 1.0.0, you can change it to 1.0.0.1. The itune connect will allow you to upload

Comment: I went back into Xcode. Did a clean, build, and then archive again. It worked fine this time. Not sure what was different...

Answer (score 3):

For those who are having issues like this on Xcode 6.1

### Issue

Xcode 6.1 is still beta (14 October 2014).
You can't submit apps built or using any beta software.

### Solution

Simply revert to the Xcode 6.0.1 from Apple Store

Answer (score 1):

Found on another forum:
Add a user defined setting to Build Settings:
"CFBundleShortVersionString" with the value of the version as in General, Identity.

This validated and has been accepted.