# Xcode 5.1.1 - The bundle is invalid. New apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be built with public

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm receiving the error: **The bundle is invalid. New apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be built with public** when I try to validate my app (using Archive XCode). I'm using iOS 7 SDK and Xcode 5.1.1

Comment: Same here, I already sent a message to their dev support team

Comment: Please search - this was asked just a few minutes ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754934/apps-and-app-updates-submitted-to-the-app-store-must-be-built-with-xcode-5-1-1-o

Comment: It looks like they fixed it, I just successfully validated my app